# Gracefully close ReactPhp app

Tags: php, reactphp

The question is very related to [Consume only N messages from RabbitMQ with react\stomp, ack them separately and then exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672486/consume-only-n-messages-from-rabbitmq-with-react-stomp-ack-them-separately-and), but a bit more general.

For example, I have a slow I/O operation:

```
$port = 4000;

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$socket = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$socket->on('connection', function ($conn) use ($loop){

    $conn->on('data', function ($data) use ($conn, $loop) {

        if ($data == 42) {
            // this instantly stop the loop
            $loop->stop();
        }

        $process = new React\ChildProcess\Process('sleep 5; echo ' . $data);

        $loop->addTimer(0.001, function($timer) use ($process, $conn) {
            $process->start($timer->getLoop());

            $process->stdout->on('data', function($output) use ($conn) {
                if ($output) {
                    $conn->write("> $output");
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
echo "Socket server listening on port $port.\n";
echo "You can connect to it by running: telnet localhost $port\n";
$socket->listen($port);
$loop->run();
echo "exited";
```

when I run `$loop->run();` I want to stop it at some point, e.g. by timer, after accepting N requests, or any other event, like `pcntl_signal`, or data assertion, as in the example.

The challenge is to finish all started jobs before exit, and I cannot figure out how to achieve it.

In the server console I have:

```
Socket server listening on port 4000.
You can connect to it by running: telnet localhost 4000
exited
```

In the client console I have:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
1
2
3
4
5
> 1
> 2
42
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

where 1,2,3,4,5 were entered with 1 sec interval

Instead I would like to see something like this:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
1
2
3
4
5
> 1
> 2
42
> 3
6
> 4
> 5
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: Depending on how you handle this, you need a callback that has access to `$loop`, and then simply call `$loop->stop()`, I believe

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: `$loop->stop()` stops the loop. I have updated the question to make it a bit more clear, that I need the loop to finish all started jobs before exit the script.

Comment: So disconnect the socket first then, and when the queue is empty - stop the loop and process will exit. However, where's the guarantee that you process won't hang?

Comment: @N.B. Thanks, that makes sense. Do you have any idea how to check if the queue is empty ? A process can hung at any time, it is not the subject. It is ok to exit immediately on SIGKILL. The challenge is to exit gracefully on SIGTERM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, to exit gracefully you need to track running processes and stop the loop only when all processes are finished:

```php
$socket->on('connection', function ($conn) use ($loop) {
    $processes = new SplObjectStorage();
    $stop = false;

    $conn->on('data', function ($data) use ($conn, $loop, $processes, &$stop) {
        if ('42' === trim($data)) {
            $stop = true;
            if (!$processes->count()) {
                $loop->stop();
            }
        }

        if ($stop) {
            return;
        }

        $process = new React\ChildProcess\Process('sleep 5; echo ' . $data);
        $processes->attach($process);

        $process->on('exit', function () use ($process, $processes, &$stop, $loop) {
            $processes->detach($process);

            if ($stop && !$processes->count()) {
                $loop->stop();
            }
        });

        $loop->addTimer(0.001, function($timer) use ($process, $conn) {
            $process->start($timer->getLoop());

            $process->stdout->on('data', function($output) use ($conn) {
                if ($output && '42' !== trim($output)) {
                    $conn->write("> $output");
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, it is exactly the workaround I ended up with. I don't believe data-handling function is the right place to keep loop management code, but it seems there is no better approach =(

Comment: Well, a better approach would be to emit your own 'finished' event, and attach a callback with loop management logic to it.